# How to reference a FormControlName within a nested FormControlGroup?

Tags: angular

I am trying to reference a FormControl from within a nested FormGroup.

Below, I am able to reference ***firstName*** correctly

```
this.emailForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: new FormControl()
})

<input formControlName="firstName" />
```

But when I wrap firstName with another FormGroup, that same referencing is not working.
Below, I have tried to reference it, but it is not working:

```
this.emailForm = this.fb.group({
    personalInfo: new FormGroup({
        firstName: new FormControl()
    })

})

<input formControlName="['personalInfo'].firstName" />
```

Here is the error message I am getting:

> Error: Cannot find control with name: '[personalInfo].firstName'

Can someone please tell me what changes I need to make so that I can reference the nested FormControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not referencing the control in the right way:

Remove `['personalInfo']` from the `formControlName` attribute and add a `div` with a `formGroupName='personalInfo'` attribute and value, just before your control to reference the nested group in your form.

```
<div formGroupName='personalInfo'>
<input formControlName="firstName" />
```

More info in the [FormGroupName docs] (https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupName)